# How to find TPH equivalence to SMD parts

Tags: diodes, surface-mount

I'm trying to reproduce the following schematic but it's designed with SMD components, I want to build it with the TPH equivalents, the problem is with diodes, I have found S1A is equivalent to 1N4001 diode but what about SS24?

[image]

Comment: Not every part is available in both kinds of packages, you need to figure out what paramters matter and then just find a part with the same parameters.

Comment: Just a warning: Switching converters, like this buck converter, are very sensitive to PCB layout. You can make it with through-hole parts, but if your PCB layout is bad you may see degraded performance. If you bread-board it, it's likely to work poorly, if at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find Key features of the component

i.e. for a diode
- maximum Forward voltage drop 
- I ave
- I peak
- power dissipation
- Temperature rating

Go to a site such as Farnell. Select the above criteria as filters. Select all through hole components and that should get you relevant components. Make sure to double check with the component datasheet when you find a component you like.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily find them yourself using the catalogs of the suppliers.
Like [Digikey](https://www.digikey.nl/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/diodes-rectifiers-single/280) or [Element14](http://www.newark.com/c/semiconductors-discretes/diodes/schottky-diodes).

For example: **[SB340-E3](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88719/sb320.pdf)**